# Custom RichTextBox Event Handle

Tags: c#, events, richtextbox

I'm new to Custom Controls and I'm looking for some help.

I want to know if it is possible to add validation on an event such as a "Key_Press" within my Custom Class rather than through an Event in my form code. I aim to block the use of the Return & Enter keys for the control.

I have created a custom RichTextBox, code below :-

```
public class CustomRTB : RichTextBox
    {
        protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
        {

            if ((keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V)))
            {
                IDataObject iData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();

                if (iData.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
                {
                    string contents = Clipboard.GetText().Replace("\r\n", " "); 
                    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, contents);
                    this.Paste();
                }

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this winforms, webforms wpf?

But isn't it possible to handle the KeyDown or KeyUp events on the Rtb?

Comment: Its for a win form. I want the custom control to do this automatically rather than put the code in the Form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block the Enter key by simply overriding the OnKeyDown() method.  An example of a plain KeyDown event that works for any RTB:

```
    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter) e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, sure.  As I noted, override OnKeyDown.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to custom controls and events. I have it working now from what you explained, thank you very much for your advice.